# Activity does not for an unknown reason

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

**LogCat:**

```
03-24 00:27:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(13836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxx.yyyyyy/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyy.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is what I see in logCat when trying to launch the application. But it seems to me that my code is OK, so I do not have an idea what the problem is, please help! Thanks in advance.

```
Main.java

package com.xxxxxx.yyyyyy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;  



public class Main extends Activity
{

Button start;

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(0x7f030010);
    start = (Button)findViewById(0x7f080047);
    start.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Tab1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}


}
```

Comment: `an unknown reason` is called an NPE.

Comment: It's really a bad and dangerous practice to use the ids directly. Not only is not readable, but if you will change anything in your design, then... good luck!

Comment: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxx.yyyyyy/com.xxxxxx.yyyyyy.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException`  Nothing unknown about it.  The log will also tell you exactly what line it happens on.  As others have said, that hardcoded ID is almost certainly the problem.  Every time you change your resources and rebuild, it will change.  `findViewById()` will then return null and boom - `NullPointerException`.  Also, `it seems to me that my code is OK`, if that was true, you would not get a crash!

Comment: My comp crashed once and I have lost everything except apk files, so I decompiled them and it looks as it looks, with hardcoded ids..

Comment: Just restore from your backups.  If you don't back up, then sorry, nothing anyone can do and you have learned a hard lesson.  As it is, it is probably quicker to rewrite the app than to try to fix it up after decompilation.  Also, please post the stack trace from logcat so that we can confirm the error.  If all you are doing is recompiling, then the IDs will not change so it may well be a different problem.

Comment: @Simon I will tell you a scary story:) It might be not a good practice but anyway I used to save my workspace folder on some cloudservice in the end of each day, and one day i needed to get my folder from there but I was shocked when found an empty catalog...Technical Support did not have any idea gow this could happen so they just appologized

Comment: That is scary!  To give you an idea of how seriously I take my backups, I have my source automatically backed up to 3 cloud services and 2 local hard disk backups.  One is a separate physical drive on my PC, the other is a NAS.  It is also in a local GIT server with a backup of the entire GIT folder to the another cloud service and a PC at my office!  I think I've got it covered ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why hardcode values? No need for that.

When you add a button with the id in your layout there is automatic entry in `R.java`. When you initialize your views you just reference the id.

Just make sure your layout has a button and you just reference the same in your activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
```

There is also a possibility something in `Tab1` being null.

Comment: My comp crashed once and I have lost everything except apk files, so I decompiled them and it looks as it looks, with hardcoded ids..

Comment: @user3158610 you start again. Never hardcode values

Comment: Thank you, i did change ids to normal ones and application starts. But actually in other recovered apps i didnt have to do that, they work fine with hardcoded ids..

Comment: @user3158610 well it may work but that is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

most likely your start variable is null. Use the resources as described by Raghunandan in order to retrieve the Button reference.